# method parameter that accepts a class of a specific type

Tags: java

Assuming I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Car {

}
```

An inner class extension of the above class:

```
public class Foo {

   public static final class BMW extends Car {
        public final Foo foo = new Foo("foo");
   }

}
```

How do I create a method that accepts the class `BMW`?

My current method:

```
void listInstances(final Class<Car> clazz) {}
```

Gives this error:

```
incompatible types: Class<Foo.BMW> cannot be converted to Class<Car>
```

When I call it like:

```
listInstances(Foo.BMW.class);
```

Comment: `Class<BMW>` or `Class<? extends Car>`

Comment: Signature should be `listInstances(Class<Foo.BMW> clazz)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pillar is correct...

```
void listInstances(Class<Car>)
```

...must take in the Car class object and only the Car class object.  Alternatively...

```
void listInstances(Class<? extends Car>);
```

Can take in any Class object for a class that extends Car (including Car).

It's strange (based on the name of the method) that there is no return value.  Often, when a method has such a name I see something like:

```
<T extends Car> List<T> listInstances(Class<T> type);
```

This guarantees the return type matches the input type.